# Prove that if $s = \sup(A)$ iff $s$ is an upper bound of $A$ and there exists a sequence $(s_n)$ in $A$ which converges to $s$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and bounded above. Prove that if $s = \sup(A)$ iff $s$ is an upper bound of $A$ and there exists a sequence $(s_n)$ in $A$ which converges to $s$.

---

($\implies$) Assume $s = \sup(A)$, then by definition $s$ is an upper bound of $A$. Now there are two cases for $A$, 1) it contains a finite number of elements, say $k$ of them. 2) there are an infinite number of elements in $A$. If there is only a finite number of elements, then let $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots, a_k\}$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, k$. WLOG assume $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_k$, then $\sup(A) = a_k = \max(A)$. So define the sequence $(s_n) = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k, a_k, a_k, a_k \cdots)$, then $(s_n) \rightarrow a_k = \sup(A)$.

I am not exactly sure how to handle the infinite case nor how to approach the ($\Leftarrow$) proof either. If anyone can provide a solution (or a different approach that doesn't split it into cases for the ($\implies$) proof) that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

($\Rightarrow$) We need not distinguish the cases $A$ finite or not finite:

By definition (characterization)  of the least upper bound $s=\sup(A)$:
$$\left\{\begin{array}\\a\le s,\quad\forall a\in A\;(*)\\\forall \epsilon>0,\quad \exists\; a\in A,\;\; s-\epsilon\le a\le s\\\end{array}\right.$$
so $(*)$ means that $s$ is an upper bound and let $\epsilon=\frac 1n$ then by $(**)$ there's $a_n\in A$ such that
$$s-\frac1n\le a\le s$$
and by the squeeze theorem we see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$$

($\Leftarrow$) It's pretty similar to the first proof and I leave it for you.

Comment: Wow! You were busy this past 24 hours!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the fact that
$$
s = \sup{A} \iff \text{$s$ is the lowest upper bound of $A$} \iff \forall\epsilon>0\exists x\in A\text{ such that } (s-\epsilon,s]\cap\{x\}\neq\emptyset
$$
where the last part is almost the definition of the existence of a sequence in $A$ that converges to $s$.